# Mockito unit test expected and actual results are identical but the test fails

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, verify

I have the following test method where I verify if teh service `save` method has been called:

@Test
public void testPutIngredientList() throws Exception
{
IngredientList ingredientListC = generateTestIngredientListC();

```
Mockito.doNothing().when(ingredientListService).save(ingredientListC);

MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(put("/api/ingredientLists")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(ingredientListC))
        ).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

String actualJsonResponse = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
String expectedJsonResponse = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(ingredientListC);
assertEquals(expectedJsonResponse, actualJsonResponse);

verify(ingredientListService).save(ingredientListC);
```

}

Now `assertEquals(expectedJsonResponse, actualJsonResponse);` passes but when it gets to the `verify` method, the test fails:

> Argument(s) are different! Wanted: IngredientList bean.save(
> IngredientList [id=0, ingredients=[VolumeMeasurement [id=0, ingredient=Ingredient [id=0, name=Milk], unit=450.0],
> WeightMeasurement [id=0, ingredient=Ingredient [id=0, name=Potato],
> unit=20000.0], WeightMeasurement [id=0, ingredient=Ingredient [id=0,
> name=Corn], unit=356.12]]] );
> -> at com.rest.IngredientListRestControllerTest.testPutIngredientList(IngredientListRestControllerTest.java:192)
> Actual invocations have different arguments: IngredientList bean.save(
> IngredientList [id=0, ingredients=[VolumeMeasurement [id=0, ingredient=Ingredient [id=0, name=Milk], unit=450.0],
> WeightMeasurement [id=0, ingredient=Ingredient [id=0, name=Potato],
> unit=20000.0], WeightMeasurement [id=0, ingredient=Ingredient [id=0,
> name=Corn], unit=356.12]]] );
> -> at com.rest.IngredientListRestController.updateIngredientList(IngredientListRestController.java:51)

but as far as I can tell they are exactly the same! Anyone ran into this before?

Comment: did you call the ingredientListService.save ? I can't seem to find it in your code - so I would not expect it to have been called - maybe you accidentally mocked that part away?

Comment: What is the type for an element in `ingredientListC`?  Does it have an an equals/hashcode method?

Comment: @DamianK.Bast yes it gets called by the MVC rest call to "/api/ingredientLists".

Comment: @AndrewS IngredientListC is of a custom object type I created, which I already checked before did have toString, equals and hashcode methods. However your comment prompted me to revisit the class and I discovered that it had references to other objects I defined which did not have toString, hashcode and equals defined! I added them and the test passed. Thank you :)